# Assign Javascript popup HTML link to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, escaping, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign the following to a PHP variable:

```
[<a href='"'javascript:pop_booking_item_add({ID})'"'>Add New Item</a>]
```

I have tried this:

```
$add_button = "[<a href='"'javascript:pop_booking_item_add({ID})'"'>Add New Item</a>]";
```

But I am getting the error message:

Error: syntax error, unexpected ''javascript:pop_booking_item_a' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)

I think I need to escape the quotes but I'm not sure how to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`$add_button = "[<a href='javascript:pop_booking_item_add({ID})'>Add New Item</a>]";`

or

`$add_button = "[<a href=\"javascript:pop_booking_item_add({ID})\">Add New Item</a>]";`

Answer (score 1):

`&quot;` is a valid replacement for `'` or `"` in mixed HTML / javascript. Have you tried with :

```php
$add_button = "[<a href=&quot;javascript:pop_booking_item_add({ID});&quot;>Add New Item</a>]";
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't it better to do it like this?

```
<a href="#" class="classnameofyourlink" data-id="3">link</a>

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.classnameofyourlink'), function (el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // put your stuff here
        // retrieve the {{ID}} like this: this.getAttribute('data-id'));
    }, false);
});
```